# How to get this collation in sort?

Tags: sort, locale, i18n

I need to set up command sort, so it is sorting lines into this order:

```
Akira Kurosawa
Al Ernest Garcia
Alain Sarde
Alan Ladd, Jr.
Albert S. Ruddy
Alberto Grimaldi
Alfred Hitchcock
Amanda Plummer
Frank Pesce
Fred Roos
Fulvio Morsella
Günter Rohrbach
Gale Anne Hurd
Gary Kurtz
```

(notice handling of whitespace and position of Günter Rohrbach).

I tried various settings of `LC_ALL` and `LC_COLLATE`, but I never get this order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `ko_KR.utf8` works, try

```
LC_COLLATE=ko_KR.utf8 sort file
```

---

How have I found this?

```
for loc in $(locale -a);
    do echo ____"${loc}"____; LC_COLLATE="$loc" sort file;
done | pcregrep -MC1 'wa\nAl (\n|[^_])*Günter Rohrbach\nG'
```

Comment: i like how you found it.